# Console TTY displays on integrated Intel HD3000's monitor instead of NVidia GPU's monitor

Tags: xorg, console, nvidia, multi-monitor, intel-graphics

I've got two monitors attached to my desktop PC's GPU (a GeForce 560Ti) that work fine for X.

When I switch to the console TTY, however, both monitors show nothing. The console TTY is being displayed, but Linux is using the integrated HD3000 GPU to do it - as I discovered when I attached a monitor to the appropriate port.

Can I make the console TTY appear via the NVidia GPU instead? I'm not bothered about which of its monitors it appears on - I'd just like the output to go via the right GPU!

System is: `Linux tlinux 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.63-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux`. The NVidia driver is the proprietary 319.82 - it's the one you install from the default Debian package manager.

Comment: You can also try to blacklist Intel's graphics module, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253326/nixos-no-login-prompt-in-virtual-terminals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turns out to be related to a BIOS setting.

I don't know if this setting has the same name in every BIOS, but in mine (AMIBIOS) it's called `iGPU Multi-monitor`. (It can be found in the `Advanced` > `System Agent Configuration` > `Graphics` section.) Set it to `[Disabled]`, and the TTYs will appear on the PCI-E GPU's monitor.